# How can I retrieve my JSON output into a JavaScript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have my jsonOutput.php page like this :

```
 $response['imgsrc'] =  $filename[1];
 echo json_encode($response);
```

It outputs a filename like `{"imgsrc":"071112164139.jpg"}`

Now my question is, how can I use jQuery in my index.php to get the filename into a variable using ajax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('jsonOutput.php', function(data) {
  var filename = data.imagesrc;
});
```

Comment: Yes, `$.getJSON` is a shorthand for `$.ajax()` call with `dataType` as `json`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Oh... hehe sorry! Posted the comment on the wrong answer :P I was looking at the answer with `$.get` :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.get('<your php file>', {}, function(response) {
   var imagesrc = response.imgsrc;
   alert(response.imgsrc);
});
```

Have a read through http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have to specify a `dataType` parameter when dealing with `json` data?

Comment: Not if your server is correctly sending back the application/json Content-Type, I believe.

Comment: Well I would say its always better to be verbose. As we are not talking about servers here but client side technologies, I would recommend always specifying the `dataType`. This will also increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

All you'll have to do is execute a jQuery ajax call -

```
var imgSrc = '';
$.ajax(PATH_TO_PHP_SCRIPT,{},function(response){
  imgSrc = response.imgsrc;
},'json');
```

Your `imgsrc` parameter will now be a JavaScript variable called `imgSrc`. Don't forget to specify that your `dataType` is a `json`.

#### Reference -

- [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse json output into a javascript object.

Following code would work:

```
var json = json_encode(<?php echo $response ?>);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
alert("file name is: " + obj.imgsrc);
```